# Convert date /Date(665812800000)/ to 06/02/1991

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, scripting

I need help in this conversion: `Date(665812800000)` to `06/02/1991`.

I am working with mvc 5 and ajax.

How should my code be written so that it shows correctly?

```
function buscarResutladoJS() {
    var id = $('#id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/obtenerFecha/buscarResultado',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (respuesta) {
            $('#obtener_fecha').val(respuesta.fecha);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? You've tagged `C#`, but shown Javascript code. You also have an ajax call, so you could be wanting to do this conversion in C# or in Javascript.

Comment: Hello, sorry, my English is bad, I need to recover a saved date and show it on a different table. There is where it appears / Date (665812800000) / and not the date 06/02/1991

Comment: What is `/ Date (665812800000) /`, is that just a timestamp, or some sort of object?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to `parse` this string to date like below

```js
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}

let value =  '/Date(665812800000)/'

let result = ToJavaScriptDate(value);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Could that regex not just be `/\d+/`?

Comment: string contain Date and / character

Comment: But if you already know the input, you can use a simpler expression.

Comment: @Hien Nguyen, thank you very much for your help. But how can I integrate it into my code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link related to the date different format. Include the javascript and Css file of [moment function](https://momentjs.com) to convert the date into different format.

Example

```js
 
 $('#obtener_fecha').val( moment(respuesta.fecha).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```